# what is causing data not to be inserted into db table?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I want to perform an insert into the database so that the database table `Individual Answer` contains the following data:

Individual_Answer Table:

```
AnswerId  AnswerMarks
295       2
296       1
297       1
298       3
299       3
```

Problem is that it is not inserting into database. Is it the php/mysqli code which is causing the problem or is it the ajax that is not accessing the php page which is doing the insert (`insertmarks.php`)?

Below in my code in php/mysqli:

```
<?php

 // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

var_dump($_POST);  

 $answersql = "INSERT INTO Individual_Answer (AnswerId, AnswerMarks) 
    VALUES (?, ?)";

if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
}



//make sure both prepared statements succeeded before proceeding
if($insertanswer)
{
   $c = count($_POST['answerId']);

    for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ )
    {


$insertanswer->bind_param('ii', $_POST['answersId'][$i], $_POST['answerMarks'][$i]);

}
    //close your statements at the end

    $insertanswer->close();
}

?>
```

Below is the `var_dump($_POST)` outputting:

```
array(7) { 
["q1_ans_org"]=> string(1) "4" 
["q1_ans"]=> string(1) "0" 
["answerMarks"]=> array(5) 
{ 
[0]=> string(1) "2" 
[1]=> string(1) "1" 
[2]=> string(1) "1" 
[3]=> string(1) "3" 
[4]=> string(1) "3" } 
["q2_ans_org"]=> string(1) "6" 
["q2_ans"]=> string(1) "0" 
["num_groups"]=> string(1) "2" 
["submitMarks"]=> string(12) "Submit Marks" 
}
```

Below is the html and jquery/ajax code which is suppose to access insertmarks.php:

```
<form id="Marks" action="penalty.php" method="post">

...

<p>
<input type='hidden' id='num_groups' name='num_groups' value='<?php echo$questionId?>'>
<input id="submitBtn" name="submitMarks" type="submit" value="Submit Marks" />
</p>

</form>

...

<script type="text/javascript">

myClickHandler = function(e) {
       var ng = $('#num_groups').val();
       for (var group = 1; group <= ng; group++) {
         if (!validation(group)) return false;
       }
       if (confirm("Make sure that your marks are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any of your marks for this Assessment." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n")) {
         $.ajax({
           url: "insertmarks.php",
           data: $("#Marks").serialize(),
           async: false,
           type: "POST"
         });
         return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    };

    $('#Marks').submit(myClickHandler);

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) the query,

```
$insertanswer->execute();
```

Comment: Can I quickly ask where to put this in my code because I put this line of code right above the close() statement but it only inserts one row `AnswerId: 299  AnswerMarks: 3`, it does not insert the other values

Comment: @user1881090 put it after the bind statement.